# How can I shoot a clear video when under the rain with a GoPro?

Tags: shooting

I use a GoPro 10 to record videos. The GoPro is placed on a car. How can I shoot a clear video when under the rain with a GoPro?

Currently, the rain makes the videos very unclear:

[image]

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.